# Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ConnectionStrings' and no extension method 'ConnectionStrings' accepting

Tags: c#

I've been stuck with  this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Supplier;
{
    public partial class Supplier : Form
    {
        public Supplier()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public object ConfigurationManager { get; private set; }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
             con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;

             string command = "insert into Supplier (SupplierID, SupplierName, Address, City, Country, ContactName, Position, Product) values (@SupplierID, @SupplierName, @Address, @City, @Country, @ContactName, @Position, @Product)";

             SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(command, con);
             com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

I get the error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ConnectionStrings' and no extension method 'ConnectionStrings' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found...

on the line

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constring"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: The error explains everything. You have a field of type `object` and try to call a method on it that simply doesn't exist. I suspect though that you *don't* want that field at all and wanted to use [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) but forgot to add the namespace. When the compiler complained, you selected the very first fix which created this field

Comment: Why do you have a property called `ConfigurationManager` in this class?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a reference to  `System.Configuration.dll` and also include the `using System.Configuration;` in your "using" section

Comment: And remove the ConfigurationManager field

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all!
I removed the object, added the using System.Configuration and also added a reference to System.Configuration form the References tab.
It worked!